# Elementary school prankster on a "looping" curriculum who "marries" his crush

Tags: identification-request

Looking for a kid's story I read sometime between 2004 and 2007. It was a book intended for readers around my age at the time, between the ages of 7-10 or so. I unfortunately can't remember if it was a series of short books, or one chaptered book; even if it was a series, I do recall it having (short) chapters, as well as at least one illustration (I think in black and white) per chapter. The book is in English.

Here are some details I remember. As I said, I don't remember if it was one book or several, so I can't say for sure how many of these scenes took place in the same book:

- The book is about a class of students in elementary school, younger than 6th grade and probably younger than 5th grade, focusing in particular on 3-4 students.
- The main character had a crush on a girl in his class, and they get "married" on the playground. I think the girl's name started with an S.
- The main character is a prankster. In one scene, he tricks another kid into thinking he (the main character) spat on a piece of grass. In reality, the "spit" is from a spittlebug, a small insect that produces white foam to cover itself for protection. Later, the main character really does spit on a piece of grass to complete the joke.
- At one point, the main character and his friend are coming back to school after summer vacation, but they become nervous when they find that the layout of the school is different and there's a new receptionist. When they finally find their classroom, they learn that they have the same teacher and classmates from last year. The teacher explains that the school is now on a "looping" curriculum, where everyone has the same classmates and teacher throughout all of elementary school.

For the life of me I have no idea what the name of this book or series was, or any of the characters names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Horrible Harry* series by Suzy Kline seems to match.

The "marriage" episode could be from *Horrible Harry and the Kickball Wedding*. According to [goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2738575618?book_show_action=true) Harry decides to ask his crush, Song Lee, to marry him, when a kickball game gets in the way.

*Song Lee and the Leech Man* has the "spit" scene:

> “Eeyew!” Sidney said. “Harry just spit!”
>
> We all turned and looked at the froth on the leaf.
>
> Professor Guo laughed. “That wasn't Harry. That's just a spittlebug
> building a house of bubbles.”
>
> “Fooled yah, Sid!” Harry cackled.

From *Horrible Harry and the Drop of Doom*:

> “And your teacher will be...”
>
> I was disappointed she didn't reach for an envelope like on the
> Academy Awards.
>
> “... me.”
>
> No one said anything. It took a while to sink in.
>
> Miss Mackle explained, “It's called looping. That's when the teacher
> moves to the next grade with her class.”